# Oracle SQL NOT BETWEEN not return correct data

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I'm looking to return all items not currently hired out, this is defined by start and end date of each item.

I created the following code but this doesn't return the correct results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT item.ITEM_ID, details.barcode
  FROM item
  JOIN details ON item.ITEM_ID = details.ITEM_ID
 WHERE (item.HIRE_DATE NOT BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
                               AND TO_DATE('11/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'))
   AND item.END_DATE NOT BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
                             AND TO_DATE('11/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

I've included a small extract of my table to explain what I need:

```
 Hire_Date | End_Date   | Item_ID
-------------------------------------
01/01/2015 | 03/01/2015 | ItemID_12
06/01/2015 | 07/01/2015 | ItemID_12
03/01/2015 | 10/01/2015 | ItemID_5
02/01/2015 | 04/01/2015 | ItemID_8
12/01/2015 | 15/01/2015 | ItemID_10
11/01/2015 | 20/01/2015 | ItemID_4
15/01/2015 | 16/01/2015 | ItemID_5
01/01/2015 | 03/01/2015 | ItemID_3
07/01/2015 | 10/01/2015 | ItemID_3
01/01/2015 | 07/01/2015 | ItemID_2
10/01/2015 | 15/01/2015 | ItemID_12
16/01/2015 | 20/01/2015 | ItemID_3
05/01/2015 | 15/01/2015 | ItemID_8
16/01/2015 | 20/01/2015 | ItemID_10
10/01/2015 | 15/01/2015 | ItemID_2
```

In the above table, if I set my start date to `06/01/2015` and my end date to `10/01/2015` it would only return `ItemID_4` & `ItemID_10` because these aren't used at all within that date range.

Comment: What data do you have, what does it return and what do you expect it should return?

Comment: Also note that a `null` value for `hire_date` or `end_date` will cause your condition to be false.

Comment: are you sure it shouldn't be 'mm/dd/yyyy' for your format?

Comment: Updated my post to give a little more detail

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are just looking for another expression:

```
HIRE_DATE > TO_DATE('11/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') OR END_DATE < TO_DATE('01/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
```